# How to make Tools->Git->Push work in Qt Creator

Tags: windows, git, qt-creator

When I try Tools->Git->Push in Qt Creator, I get

```
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your generated googlecode.com password; see https://code.google.com/hosting/settings
The command 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' terminated with exit code 128.
```

I have the password for the remote repository, but I couldn't find where to enter it in Qt Creator's settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question,the only solution is run it in the terminal.I didn't find a better way.Let me know if you find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that resolved the problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70101716/7511257

It was easy for me:

`git push --set-upstream origin master`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a credential helper to tell Git to remember your GitHub username and password every time it talks to GitHub.

You will need to set this up from the cmd line initially but then your password will be cached and Qt Creator -> remote repository -> push will work as expected.

1. Setup Windows credential helper from the terminal:

   `git config --global credential.helper wincred`
2. Perform a push and enter your password when prompted:

   `git push`

Your password is now cached for all future push actions and so pushing from Qt Creator also works.